# Incorrect value in Discussion flag page total

Tags: bug, discussions-space, moderator-tools

**Scenario 01**

Four items are on the list, and it always shows +1.

[image]

---

**Scenario 02**

There are only 5 Items there, and it shows 9 in total.

[image]

Comment: I think this page is visible only to discussion moderators? It might make sense to redact the discussion titles as well since that flagging is not public info from what I understand.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Generally, we don't consider the mere fact that a post was flagged to be private information, though it's true that it's (mostly) not publicly visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discussions flags on the all flags page (only visible to Discussions moderators, site moderators, and staff) are grouped by post. The total number at the top includes all the flags on every post.

So if there were five posts that each had one flag, and then a sixth post that itself had five flags (whether they were all of the same type, or a combination of different flag types), the total at the top should show 10.

The number of flags of each type on a particular post is visible within the box for that post. You can also see whether each flag is attached to the post itself, or a reply on that post, where it says either "Post Flags" or "Reply Flags". In some cases there will be both.

Does that explain the discrepancy you are noticing, or is there something else that seems off?

Comment: Interesting. That's the opposite of how flags are summarized for site moderators on questions, answers, and comments in the admin flag dashboard. In the admin flagging dashboard, the summarized numbers are a count of posts with one or more flags, not a count of total number of flags. When looking at a single post or comment within the normal moderator flag dashboard, you do see the count (and list) of the flags on that post and comments, but even if there's 100 flags associated with that post, it only counts as 1 post with flags.

Comment: A bit more consistency in how these are displayed would be helpful. I'd recommend changing everything to "total flags" and the fact that it's "posts with flags" in the admin dashboard is something that comes up as confusing to new moderators on a regular basis. Maybe provide both numbers? At a minimum, it should be clearer what is being shown (e.g., when the count of posts with flags is used with a label that's just "flags", perhaps a tooltip with something like "count of posts with one or more flags" would be useful).

Comment: If anything, i think the wording in this case is clear given the number is next to "Flags" and not "Discussions". there are 4 discussions and 5 flags in the first screenshot, that aligns pretty well. Wouldn't be the worst thing to *also* display the 4. *"4 Discussions - 5 Flags"*

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug but the result of two of the same flags on the same post nesting together, like so:

[image: 2 flag icon]

Note: When there are different types of flag under the same Discussion, they are prominently [listed on separate lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtwO4.png), making it more obvious.

When I handled those two nested flags, the flag count dropped by two, and thus there was only one flag per flagged post.